# Storing and retrieving a value and updating it

Tags: objective-c, arrays, math

I am creating an iphone app with objective-c. I have a math problem I need help on. I am new at this so I need to keep it simple. Any sample code would be appreciated.

This is the problem I want to display

> person A (UItext input ) earns $x a day(UIText input)  and keeps a total $y(UILabel).
>   person b (UItext input ) earns $x a day(UIText input)  and keeps a total $y.
>   person c (UItext input ) earns $x a day(UIText input)  and keeps a total $y.
>                                                         Grand Total= $z

I can not figure out how I store total , retrieve it, then update the total value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create an array of Person objects that have name, earnings and savings properties. Then use collection operators to calculate the "grand total". Refer to [Key Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

```
NSNumber *grandTotal = [people valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.savings"];
[grandTotalLabel setText:[grandTotal stringValue]];
```

Comment: OK so now  I am thinking  create a mutablearrray named People that holds each earning object entered and then use the NSNumber *grandtotal to sum all the earnings objects in the array....is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer to your question, but you need to watch the free videos from Stanford University on iTunes U.  [iPhone Application Development (Winter 2010)](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=384233225)   It will give you a basic understanding of developing for iOS platform.

Then when you are finish watching those, follow this [How To Create A Simple iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1) tutorial step by step.  Trust me.